# Android User Interface like NumberPicker but data from SQLIte

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, listview

How could I make a user Interface like the one with NumberPicker but the data came from the SQLite. Is there a Layout for this?

[Like this User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsetN.png)

What do they call this Interface?
I'd like to create a view data from SQLite. Some what like

```
Apple

Banana

*Cake*

Donut

Eclair
```

Don't recommend using DialogFragment. I wanna do like this

[Scrollable List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6gvK.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've been looking for.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=antistatic.spinnerwheel.demo

Source code: https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no layout that does that out of the box, so you will have to do a lot of heavy lifting before getting things working. But the easiest way is to use `NumberPicker` and pass to it the values that you want to display as an array with `setDisplayedValues`. But you still have to create the connection to the database and query for the cursor that you will have to transform somehow to an ordered array, for which you can then map the values of the `NumberPicker` to the actual values in the database (told you, not easy...).

There is no easy way out of this, you could also try making your own component or buy one that does this for you.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I just might do that component. I was just hopeful maybe somebody out there have it already. :)